# In FactoryBoy, how do I setup my factory with an empty many-to-many member field?

Tags: python-3.x, django, unit-testing, django-3.0, factory-boy

I'm using Django 3 with Python 3.8.  I have the following model ...

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType, blank=False)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_phone')
    email = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_email')
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

I have created the following factory (using Factory boy) to attempt create the model in a test ...

```
class CoopFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    """
        Define Coop Factory
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Coop

    name = "test model"
    enabled = True
    phone = factory.SubFactory(PhoneContactMethodFactory)
    email = factory.SubFactory(EmailContactMethodFactory)
    web_site = "http://www.hello.com"

    @factory.post_generation
    def addresses(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            # Simple build, do nothing.
            return

        if extracted:
            # A list of types were passed in, use them
            for address in extracted:
                self.addresses.add(address)
        else:
            address = AddressFactory()
            self.addresses.add( address )

    @factory.post_generation
    def types(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            # Simple build, do nothing.
            return

        if extracted:
            # A list of types were passed in, use them
            for type in extracted:
                self.types.add(type)
        else:
            print("Creating type ...\n")
            type = CoopTypeFactory()
            self.types.add( type )
```

but I'm having trouble creating a factory with a many-to-many field (types) that is empty.  I tried the below

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_coop_create_with_no_types(self):
    """ Test customer model """    # create customer model instance
    coop = CoopFactory.create(types=[])
    print("size: ", coop.types.all().count())
    self.assertIsNotNone(coop)
    self.assertIsNotNone( coop.id )
```

but the value of `types.all().count()` is always equal to 1.  How do I properly setup a factory with an empty many-to-many field?

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, what's the right way to pass in the member field to be used by the factory?  I tried

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_coop_create_with_existing_type(self):
    """ Test customer model """    # create customer model instance
    coop_from_factory = CoopFactory()
    self.assertIsNotNone(coop_from_factory)

    coop_types = coop_from_factory.types
    coop = CoopFactory.create(types=[coop_types.all().first()], addresses=coop_from_factory.addresses.all())
    self.assertIsNotNone(coop)
```

but got this error, for the line "for _ in range(extracted):" line ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/tests/test_models.py", line 48, in test_coop_create_with_existing_type
    coop = CoopFactory.create(types=coop_types, addresses=coop_from_factory.addresses.all())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 564, in create
    return cls._generate(enums.CREATE_STRATEGY, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 141, in _generate
    return super(DjangoModelFactory, cls)._generate(strategy, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 501, in _generate
    return step.build()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 296, in build
    postgen_results[declaration_name] = declaration.declaration.call(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/factory/declarations.py", line 622, in call
    return self.function(
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/tests/factories.py", line 128, in types
    for _ in range(extracted):
TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is to change `if extracted` to `if extracted is not None`.

## Explanation

In Python, an empty list is falsey<sup>1</sup> but is not `None`.

> ```py
> coop = CoopFactory.create(types=[])
> ```

The empty list `[]` is passed to the post-generation hook `types`, as the parameter `extracted`.

> ```py
> @factory.post_generation
> def types(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
>     if not create:
>         # Simple build, do nothing.
>         return
>
>     if extracted:
>         # A list of types were passed in, use them
>         for type in extracted:
>             self.types.add(type)
>     else:
>         print("Creating type ...\n")
>         type = CoopTypeFactory()
>         self.types.add( type )
> ```

Since `if extracted` is a truth value test<sup>1</sup>, the falsey empty list falls to the `else` block where a `type` is created. So, the value of `types.all().count()` is equal to 1.

<sup>1</sup> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 0):

Skip the

```
        else:
            print("Creating type ...\n")
            type = CoopTypeFactory()
            self.types.add( type )
```

Which always will create CoopType as default.

One thing that may not be clear from documentation is [@factory.post_generation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=post_generation#post-generation-hooks) hooks are always called. That means that the else statements in all the post_generation hooks in the example code will always be called.

More info: [Simple Many-to-many relationship](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#simple-many-to-many-relationship)

Pattern I use often if I want to create default values directly is
adding a function to the factory, which in this example, would translate to:

```
@factory.post_generation
def create_types(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    if not create:
        # Simple build, do nothing.
        return

    if extracted:
        for _ in range(extracted):
            self.types.add(CoopTypeFactory())
```

Enables to use `CoopFactory(create_types=3)`.

Here's my full example:

```
@factory.post_generation
def types(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    if not create:
        # Simple build, do nothing.
        return

    if extracted:
        # A list of types were passed in, use them
        for type in extracted:
            self.types.add(type)
    # Removed this because it always creates 1 CoopType as default and
    # it may not be the desired behaviour for all tests.
    # else:
    #     print("Creating type ...\n")
    #     type = CoopTypeFactory()
    #     self.types.add( type )

# Adding this function to have a simple way of just adding default CoopTypes
@factory.post_generation
def create_types(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    if not create:
        # Simple build, do nothing.
        return

    if extracted: # This must be an integer
        for _ in range(extracted):
            self.types.add(CoopTypeFactory())
```

This gives the optional usages:

`CoopFactory(create_types=3)` will call the create_types and put int 3 in param extracted and create 3 default CoopTypes. (This enables simple use)

`CoopFactory(types=[CoopTypeFactory()])` will call the types and put a list of 1 CoopType in param extracted. (This enables more control over how CoopTypes are created if those objects needs some specific values)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this.  When using "for _ in range(extracted):", what's the right way to pass in non-empty arguments for my member field?  I have added the error I'm getting as an edit to my question in response to your suggestion.

Comment: It looks like you not passing an integer in the errorlog. I added a more verbose explanation.  I hope it clarifies.

Comment: Oh I see you're passing in a number and telling it to create X number of those types.  I was actually looking for a way to pass in a collection of objects that the factory would use for types.  In other words, I want to say, create this object, use all the default fields, but if I specify "types", then use what I specify.